# Finding the mode of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When creating a method to find the mode of an array, I see people iterating over the array through a hash with default value `0`:

```
def mode(array)
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  array.each do |i|
    hash[i]+=1
  end
end
```

or

```
freq = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
```

Can someone explain the following part of the block?

```
hash[i] = hash[i] + 1 or h[v] = h[v] + 1
```

How does the iterator know to add `+1` to each unique key of the hash? For example:

```
array = [1,1,1,2,3]
freq = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
#=> {1:3, 2:1, 3:1}
```

If someone can explain how to find the mode of an array, I would be grateful.

Comment: Er, the code is as clear as it could possibly be, I don't know how to explain it better. The Hash just uses a counter for every value, with the default value of `0`, increase `1` every time it sees a value again.

Comment: `{1:3, 2:1, 3:1}` is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you first example, you need the method to return the hash that is created, or do some manipulation of the hash to compute the mode.  Let's try it, just returning the hash (so I've added `hash` as the last line):

```
def hash_for_mode(array)
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  array.each do |i|
    hash[i]+=1
  end
  hash
end

array = [1,3,1,4,3]
hash_for_mode(array) #=> {1=>2, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```

With `hash_for_mode` you can easily compute the mode.

By defining the hash `h = Hash.new(0)`, we are telling Ruby that the default value is zero.  By that, we mean that if a calculation is performed that depends on `h[k]` when `k` is not a key of `h`, `h[k]` will be set equal to the default value.

Consider, for example, when the first value of `array` (`1` in my example) is passed into the block and assigned to the block variable `i`. `hash` does not have a key `1`.  (It has no keys yet.) `hash[1] += 1` is shorthand for `hash[1] = hash[1] + 1`, so Ruby will replace `hash[1]` on the right side of the equality with the default value, zero, resulting in `hash[1] => 1`.

When the third value of `array` (another `1`) is passed into the block, `hash[1]` already exists (and equals `1`) so we just add one to give it a new value `2`.

In case you were wondering, if we have:

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
hash[1] += 1
hash         #=> {1=>1}
puts hash[2] #=> nil
hash         #=> {1=>1}
```

That is, merely referencing a key that is not in the hash (here `puts hash[2]`), does not add a key-value pair to the hash.

Another common way to do the same thing is:

```
def hash_for_mode(array)
  array.each_with_object({}) { |i,hash| hash[i] = (hash[i] || 0) + 1 }
end

hash_for_mode(array) #=> {1=>2, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```

This relies on the fact that:

```
(hash[i] || 0) #=> hash[i] if hash already has a key i
(hash[i] || 0) #=> 0 if hash does not have a key i, so hash[k]=>nil
```

(This requires that your hash does not contain any pairs `k=>nil`.)

Also, notice that rather than having the first statement:

```
hash = {}
```

and the last statement:

```
hash
```

I've used the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which returns the value of the hash. This is preferred here to using [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (a.k.a `reduce`) because you don't need to return `hash` to the iterator (no `; h` needed).

Comment: "if the hash performs a calculation with a key `k` not contained in the hash, the key value pair `k=>0` is added to the hash" - not true, it is just a default returned at a read operation. `h = Hash.new(0); puts h[1]; puts h.inspect` shows `0`, then `{}`. It is the assignment part of `+=` in OP's code that creates the key-value pair `1=>1`, after the addition of the default `0` and the literal `1`. The key pair `1=>0` is never in the hash in OP's code. +1 for the rest, though.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
array = [1,3,1,4,3]
array.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
# => {1=>2, 3=>2, 4=>1}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I don't know, that's some pretty sweet ass code.